# How to set up a wallet address without using truffle-hdwallet-provider

Tags: node.js, blockchain

I am developing a token transfer program with Nodejs. One question arose. I was wondering if there is a way to set the wallet address to send tokens to except for the truffle-hdwallet-provider library or metamask. Since this program is a backend service, it should not be sent via metamask.

Thank you.